# Question concerning the conditional convergence of some infinite products

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, infinite-product

Let ${(a_n)}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Let $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a bijective map.

> Is it possible then that $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+|a_n|)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+|a_{\sigma(n)}|)=:r<\infty$, but that at the same time
>
> $X:=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ and $Y:=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_{\sigma(n)})$ are convergent against two different real numbers $s$ and $t$?

If this cannot be the case, then why not?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Switching to logarithms, it is easy to check that the conditional convergence of
$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}(1+b_n) $$
is equivalent to the conditional convergence of
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}b_n. $$
So the first line of the problems gives that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}a_n $$
is absolutely convergent, so for any rearrangement $\sigma$ we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n = \sum_{n\geq 1}a_{\sigma(n)} $$
giving that:
$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}(1+a_n) = \prod_{n\geq 1}(1+a_{\sigma(n)}), $$
so the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand, why both of the two products $X:=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ and $Y:=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_{\sigma(n)})$ are conditionally convergent. But I am unable to see why their limits have to be equal...