# Question concerning the influence of interchanging factors of an infinite product on the value of the product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, infinite-product

I am searching for a proof of the following fact:

> If an infinite product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ of complex numbers is absolutely convergent, then its factors can be reordered without affecting the value of the product.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think that it is worth mentioning that this is closely related to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179743/question-concerning-the-conditional-convergence-of-some-infinite-products).